# Could someone give some examples where/when I should "will do" or "will be doing"?

Tags: meaning

I learned this [post](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/28260) just now.

There are some different answers. Only Monica Cellio's gives me some inspiration, which are these 2 sentences.

> I will drive home tomorrow.
>
> I will be driving home tomorrow.

Is it reasonable to view the first one as an emphasis of leaving, and the implication of latter has been given by Monica Cellio, which is "tomorrow would be a bad time for you to call me on my cell phone".

Is my understanding correct? Are there other situations or implications?

Could someone give some examples where/when I should "will do" or "will be doing"?

Comment: without any other clauses on context, there is no substantive difference between the 2. the technical difference would be that the first one, i.e., the simple future, i will drive, is , well, simpler than the 2nd, i.e., the future progressive. usually the future progressive is employed to set a context IN WHICH another action will occur, good, bad, or indifferent: I will be driving tomorrow when it is supposed to snow. I will be driving tomorrow since my car will be being repaired (now there's a good one :) )

Comment: The first is a firm statement of intention, the second is a reference to the situation I expect to find myself in tomorrow. So, yes, it could imply 'don't try to telephone me' or 'so I could meet you the day after tomorrow' or whatever.

Comment: I would rather say that the first is a statement about what will happen (a completed process—you will *be* home by the end of the day); the second is a statement about what you will be in process of doing.